# Установка прозрачности виджета Android

Tags: android-widgets, android

Здравствуйте!

Возникла следующая проблема:
  Необходимо выставить произвольный уровень прозрачности виджету. Допустим он состоит из одной вьюхи, но с произвольным drawable background.

Метод

```
RemoteView.setInt(..., "setBackgroundColor", Color.argb(...))
```

- сотрёт drawable background нафиг :-(

Как быть?

Пока есть мысли только сделать свою вьюху, у неё сделать метод который будет обходить всё и менять нужное, а в RemoteView дёргать этот метод, но насколько это верно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, единственный путь, это использовать RelatedLayout, в качестве фона подкладывать ImageView, и фон рисовать битмапом. Собственная View, к сожалению, в виджет не пролезает.